# Prepared statement error with date in Servlet

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert date in MySQL table fetched from 3 drop down box DD MM YYYY by using following code in servlet but prepared statement showing error

```
int bday1=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("bday"));
int bmonth1=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("bmonth"));
int byear1=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("byear"));
SimpleDateFormat dtformat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date1=Integer.toString(bday1)+"-"+Integer.toString(bmonth1)+"-"+Integer.toString(byear1);
java.util.Date dt = dtformat.parse(date1); 
System.out.println(date1);
ps.setDate(5,dt);
```

Last line showing error

> no suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date)
>       method java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,java.util.Calendar)
>   is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       method java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date) is not applicable
>         (actual argument java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date by method invocation conversion)

Where I have done mistake, help needed

Answer (score 3):

> java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,java.util.Calendar) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>
> java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date by method invocation conversion)

SQL Date is different then the JAVA Util Date. You should convert the JAVA Date to SQL Date before setting it to your PreparedStatement.

Instead of `ps.setDate(5,dt);` you should be doing `ps.setDate(5,new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime()));`

Comment: I have done as you mentioned here it is `java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(dtformat.parse(date1).getTime());   but now but date enter as 20-12-1992 stored in MySQL as 0021-03-02. Well my HTML code is <select > <option value=92>1992</option> this problem is due to this

Comment: You should parse the Date in correct format i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd` before putting it to your DB. If required, you can format it to any desired format such as `dd-MM-yyyy` etc. after retrieving it from the DB.